# Angular 1.5 $ctrl in view is an empty object when shown using $mdDialog

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, angular-components, mddialog

I am using angular 1.6.2 and angular-material 1.1.4. Here is the component that I use for $mdDialog:

```
class CommentReplySettingsController {
  /** @ngInject */
  constructor($mdDialog, $log) {
    this.$mdDialog = $mdDialog;
    $log.log(this.settingType);
  }

  hideDialog() {
    this.$mdDialog.hide();
  }

  cancelDialog() {
    this.$mdDialog.cancel();
  }
}

export const commentReplySettings = {
  template: require('./comment-reply-settings.html'),
  bindings: {
    settingType: '='
  },
  controller: CommentReplySettingsController
};
```

The above is converted into a component like this:

```
import angular from 'angular';

import {commentReplySettings} from './comment-reply-settings';

export const commentReplySettingsModule = 'commentReplySettings';

angular
  .module(commentReplySettingsModule, [])
  .component('app.user.commentReplySettings', commentReplySettings);
```

And here another component's controller function in which I am using the above component inside $mdDialog:

```
  showCommentReplySettingDialog(ev) {
    const _this = this;
    this.settingType = 'global';
    this.$mdDialog.show({
      template: '<app.user.comment-reply-settings class="md-dialog-container" setting-type="$ctrl.settingType"></app.user.comment-reply-settings>',
      parent: angular.element(this.$document.body),
      autoWrap: false,
      scope: _this.$scope,
      preserveScope: true,
      targetEvent: ev,
      clickOutsideToClose: true,
      fullscreen: true
    });
  }
```

Now the problem is that the variables and functions are inaccessible to the view using `$ctrl`. For example, `$ctrl.hideDialog()`, `$ctrl.cancelDialog()` and even `$ctrl.settingType` is undefined. In fact, `$ctrl` prints as an empty object in view. However, `$log.log(this.settingType);` in the constructor of dialog controller logs correct value of `settingType`. How do I fix this?

**Edit 1:** _this.$scope is accessible, here is its console log screenshot:
[image]

**Edit 2:** The issue has been fixed, I was using `md-truncate` directive inside **CommentReplySettings dialog view**. It was like `<h2 flex md-truncate>Comment Response {{$ctrl.settingType}} Settings</h2>`. As soon as I changed it to `<h2 flex class="md-truncate">Comment Response {{$ctrl.settingType}} Settings</h2>`, everything works perfect. See [github.com/angular/material/issues/10356](http://github.com/angular/material/issues/10356).

Comment: Can you share `commentReplySettings` function ?

Comment: Found the issue, I was using md-truncate inside dialog view. `<h2 flex md-truncate>Comment Response {{$ctrl.settingType}} Settings</h2>`. As soon as I changed it to `<h2 flex class="md-truncate">Comment Response {{$ctrl.settingType}} Settings</h2>`, everything works perfect. See https://github.com/angular/material/issues/10356. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
showCommentReplySettingDialog(ev) {
  this.settingType = 'global';
  this.$mdDialog.show({
    template: '<app.user.comment-reply-settings class="md-dialog-container" setting-type="$ctrl.settingType"></app.user.comment-reply-settings>',
    parent: angular.element(this.$document.body),
    autoWrap: false,
    scope: this.scope,
    preserveScope: true,
    targetEvent: ev,
    clickOutsideToClose: true,
    fullscreen: true,
    controllerAs: 'ctrl' <--Added
  });
}
```

Add **controllerAs: 'ctrl'** as above. hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, I was using `md-truncate` inside **CommentReplySettings dialog view**. It was like `<h2 flex md-truncate>Comment Response {{$ctrl.settingType}} Settings</h2>`. As soon as I changed it to `<h2 flex class="md-truncate">Comment Response {{$ctrl.settingType}} Settings</h2>`, everything works perfect. See [github.com/angular/material/issues/10356](http://github.com/angular/material/issues/10356).